# How to display MySQL data based on a column field

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make an appointment maker for potential customers. The hours that are available will depend greatly on personal schedules, so I don't want a generic calendar type appointment maker. What I was trying was an SQL DB with 4 columns [ID, Made, Date, Time] with the following types [INT, BIT, VARCHAR, VARCHAR].

When SELECTing my data and displaying it, I am attempting to have an IF statement (PHP) determine if "Made" is "00" or "01" - 00 being "appointment available", 01 being "taken".

The output does display all the rows; however, it is showing all the rows as "appointment available". One of my rows has "01" in the "Made" column, and it is still showing as available.

PHP/SQL Script after connection:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tname";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
if ($row["Made"] = '00') {
echo "<tr><td>" . $row["ID"] . "</td><td>" . 'Make An Appointment' . "</td><td>" . $row["Date"] . "</td><td>" . $row["Time"] . "</td></tr>";
}
elseif ($row["Made"] = '01') {
echo "<tr><td>" . $row["ID"] . "</td><td>" . 'Reserved' . "</td><td>" . $row["Date"] . "</td><td>" . $row["Time"] . "</td></tr>";
}
}
}
```

This is the link to the output on the website:

http://www.jpegchaos.com/appointment.php

I will continue to re-upload the .php with any attempts to see if new information displays.

Line 2 should show "Reserved" while 1 and 3 should be "Make an Appointment"

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `==`, not `=` when you're checking the `$row["Made"]`. As you have it now, the first `if` statement is *always* true, so it never gets to the `elseif`. Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tname";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($row["Made"] == '00') {
            echo "<tr><td>" . $row["ID"] . "</td><td>" . 'Make An Appointment' . "</td><td>" . $row["Date"] . "</td><td>" . $row["Time"] . "</td></tr>";
        }
        elseif ($row["Made"] == '01') {
            echo "<tr><td>" . $row["ID"] . "</td><td>" . 'Reserved' . "</td><td>" . $row["Date"] . "</td><td>" . $row["Time"] . "</td></tr>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course it had to be something simple like that. Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem, happens to everyone. :)

Comment: i'll approve as soon as it lets me.